# Setting date for a $.post to a controller

Tags: jquery

How would I pass the current date, but set the day as the 1st? This is my a `$.post` to an action:

```
$.post("/RxCard/AddAccount", {
    AccountName: $("#AccountName").val(),
    Address: $("#Address").val(),
    City: $("#City").val(),
    //...
```

Comment: `new Date().setDate(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to set the date as the 1st of the current month the following will work:

```
var date = '';
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = (dateObj.getMonth() + 1);
date += dateObj.getFullYear();

if (month < 10) {
    date += "-0" + month + "-01";
} else {
    date += "-" + month + "-01";
}
```

Edit: This is to set the date in a Y-m-d format, for example 2016-08-01

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
var date = new Date().setDate(1)
```

Then in your object add

```
Date: date,
```